# Examples of Moscow spaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples, topological-groups

A space $X$ is called *Moscow*, if for each open subset $U$ of $X$, the closure of $U$ in $X$ is the union of a family of $G‎_{δ}$‎‎‎-subsets of $X$ .

For example, every first countable $T_1$-space is Moscow.

I would love to see more examples.

Comment: If $X$ is Hausdorff and either perfectly $\kappa$-normal, of countable pseudocharacter, or extremally disconnected, then $X$ is a Moscow space; all of these are clear from the definitions. There’s a theorem that an arbitrary product of first countable spaces is a Moscow space, but I’ve not seen a proof of it.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott First, thank you for the advice. I can show that every Extremally disconnected and every perfectly $\kappa$-normal space is a moscow space by definitions, But i can not comprehend the definition of "space of countable pseudocharacter". Is it true that a space $X$ of countable pseudocharacter means every point of the space $X$ is an intersection of countably many of its neighbourhoods?

Comment: Yes: or as I would put it, every singleton is a $G_\delta$-set. Thus, **every** set in the space is a union of $G_\delta$-sets.