# Every first countable space is a moscow space.

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing

First countable space $X$ is an example of [moscow spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/288688/moscow-space-examples).

Let $U$ is an open subset of $X$ and $x\in \overline{U}$. If $\overline{U}$ is open or even a nbhood of $x$ this proposition is immediately proved by definition of first countability of space $X$.

But now how can I prove this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a first countable space each point is a $G_\delta$, so **every** set is a union of $G_\delta$ sets. In particular, then, $\operatorname{cl}U$ is a union of $G_\delta$ sets for any $U\subseteq X$. (Note that this argument really needs only that $X$ have countable pseudocharacter.)

Comment: Beat me to it with a better answer!  (Have you looked at [Paul's question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/320334/8348) from yesterday?  I got stuck at the same place Henno did.)

Comment: @Arthur: Yes, I have, and I got stuck at exactly the same place.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: why in a first countable space each point is a $G_\delta$ set? this space must be a $T_1$ space? [In a first countable T 1   space, every point is a G δ   set](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242675/topology-first-countable-axiom)

Comment: @M.Sina: It isn’t mentioned here, but Arhangel’skii’s definition included the requirement that $X$ be Tikhonov and hence $T_1$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Thank you so much. if we omit the tychonoff condition then there exist a first countable space which is not a moscow space?

Comment: @M.Sina: Yes. Let $X=[0,1]\cup\{p\}$, where $p$ is a point not in $[0,1]$. Points of $(0,1]$ have their usual nbhds, and $p$ is isolated. Basic nbhds of $0$ have the form $\{p\}\cup[0,x)$ for $x\in(0,1]$. Thus, every nbhd of $0$ contains $p$. Let $U=(0,1]$; $U$ is open in $X$, and its closure is $[0,1]$. But every $G_\delta$ containing $0$ also contains $p$, so $[0,1]$ is not the union of $G_\delta$ sets.