# Perfect mappings do not preserve the class of Moscow spaces.

Tags: general-topology

P394 of [this paper](http://topology.auburn.edu/tp/reprints/v25/tp25222.pdf) says that

> Perfect mappings do not preserve the class of Moscow spaces.

But I can not prove it by use these paper. How can i construct such an example and What is the connection between the perfect space and perfect mapping?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Corollary 2.8 of that paper, a compact space $X$ is perfect iff every continuous image of $X$ is Moscow.  Therefore a compact Moscow space which is not perfect would provide a counterexample (some continuous image of the space is not Moscow, and all continuous mappings from a compact space are perfect).  Since [all first-countable spaces are Moscow](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/321130/8348), we just need a first-countable compact space which is not perfect, equivalently not perfectly normal.

An example of such a space is the [lexicographic order topology on the unit square](http://dantopology.wordpress.com/2009/10/07/the-lexicographic-order-and-the-double-arrow-space/).  (There are likely simpler examples.)

Comment: First, thank you for following up this discussion. I found [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166864100000730), In Example 3.18. exactly the same as you describe, is considered a first-countable compact space $X$ witch is not perfectly normal but how space $Y$ is constructed?

Comment: @TXC: You're welcome for any help I have given.  However I think I am missing something now.  The article you just linked to seems to give the construction of $Y$:  First take a closed $A \subseteq X$ which is not G$_\delta$ (such exist since $X$ is not perfect), and then take $Y$ to be the quotient space $X / A$.  It goes on to explain why $Y$ is not a Moscow space.  (Clearly the quotient mapping $X \to Y$ is a continuous (hence perfect) surjection.)